# Can I travel to Italy on UK-issued refugee document?

Tags: paperwork, refugees, schengen-visas

I want to visit Italy at the end of September as a tourist. I have a refugee travel document, issued by the UK. In older refugee passports there was an additional page mentioning countries where we could go without having a separate visa in consequence of the European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees (1959) but on my passport it's not there. Someone told me people are facing problems with it so I would like confirmation:

Do I need to get a Schengen visa? If yes, where can I go in Europe without getting a visa?

Comment: I don't think the Brexit referendum should make any difference -- the UK is still a member of the EU until March 2019.

Comment: Yes that I thought but in older refugee passports there was an additional page mentioning countries where we could go without having separate visa in result of  council of abolition of visa requirement for refugee 20th April 1959 but on my passport it's not there. Someone told me people are facing problems with it so thought to conform it from experienced people here

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk IIRC the rules for refugee travel document holders are not harmonised between Schengen countries, so this isn't a duplicate of that.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but according to the Council of Europe's website [the UK suspended the application of the Agreement in 2003](http://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/031/declarations?p_auth=m1qqkljJ) and has not unsuspended it. That would seem to imply that you can't rely on that particular treaty for travel to any other country.

Answer (score 4):

Funny enough, I'm looking for the same but for Spain. While doing my searches I found that Italy changed their rules in March 17 to require visa for UK travel documents.

I have received the list from the Schengen customer inquiry as below:

> Thank you for your email.
>
> If your travel document is blue and has two golden stripes on it, you do not require a visa to travel to Denmark, Netherlands, Sweden, Switzerland, Germany, Greece, Norway, Malta and Portugal.

Comment: you need to get a visa for Spain but Italy is visa-free [2023]